# Where does powershell saves the set-executionpolicy setting?

Tags: security, powershell

I'm building some servers and need to run some powershell scripts on them. However, I need to run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Force` manually on **every** server. Because I can't set execution policy in a script. I want to know where PowerShell save the execution policy setting and want to directly change it. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ExecutionPolicy is not a single setting stored in a single place.  There are multiple scopes of ExecutionPolicy which are each set and stored differently.  Run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to see all the different scopes.

Using ProcMon to monitor what keys are being read/written when getting/setting the different scopes, I came up with this list:

- **MachinePolicy** and **UserPolicy** Can only be set via group policy.  I think the keys end up being under `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Powershell`
- **Process** does not seem to be stored in a reg key.  That makes sense, as it appies only the current process.  Probably just stored in memory.
- **CurrentUser** is stored at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell [ExecutionPolicy]` Note you could set this for a particular user (i.e. besides current user) via `HKEY_USERS`
- **LocalMachine** is stored at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell [ExecutionPolicy]`  This is the default scope when running `Set-ExecutionPolicy`.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd347641.aspx and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113394

Comment: Correct, except that `MachinePolicy` ends up altering effective settings for HKLM registry branch, and `UserPolicy` alters HKCU branch. This is actually true for any policy that differs between computer and user.

Answer (score 2):

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell
key name is ExecutionPolicy (type: REG_SZ). the value should be, in your case, RemoteSigned.